# How to make this select join query

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I've been stuck for a few hours making this query:
I have a table named "events" and another one named "user"

Each user can subscribe to an event and this gives me a Many To Many relation between both tables (with eventId as first key, and userId as second key).

I would like to get the title of an event (so e.title) and get the count of users subscribed to the most subscribed event.

Do you know how I could do this?

Currently, I have this:

```
SELECT g.title,
COUNT(MAX(u.id)) as count
FROM App\Entity\User u
JOIN u.events g WHERE g.dateStart BETWEEN :from AND :to
```

but it might be totally wrong.

Database Diagram:

[image]
(the associative table has been generated by my ORM on MYSQL, but in reality I only have the "user" and "event" table)

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Transcribing your problem in the minimal set of tables required.

```
   CREATE TABLE User (
     userId integer PRIMARY KEY,
     name varchar
   );

   CREATE TABLE Activity (
     activityId integer PRIMARY KEY,
     tile varchar,
     status varchar, 
     startTime timestamp DEFAULT current_timestamp, 
     endTime timestamp
   );

   CREATE TABLE Subscription (
     activityId integer REFERENCES Activity(id),
     userId integer REFERENCES User(id),
     PRIMARY KEY(activityId, userId)
   );
```

I call your "Event" an "Activity" to be clear you do not mean instantaneous events that occur and you want users to be notified about, if that was the case you would need an EventType or EventDefinition to which users would subscribe and a separate EventOccurrence or EventInstance table with the actual occurrences of the event. But your question only asks for ordering the Events by how many users have subscribed to them.

```
   SELECT eventId, count(userId) AS userCount
     FROM Subscription
     GROUP BY eventId
     ORDER BY userCount;
```

And of course if you want more, you just re-join to your count table. Your other WHERE clause of `startTime BETWEEN :range_low AND :range_high` is extra.

```
   WITH SubscriptionCounts AS (
     SELECT eventId, count(userId) AS userCount
       FROM Subscription
       GROUP BY eventId
   )
   SELECT *
     FROM SubscriptionCount INNER JOIN Activity USING(activityId) 
    WHERE startTime BETWEEN :range_low AND :range_high
    ORDER BY userCount DESC, startTime, title
```

there you have it.